# Как смаршрутизироваться на текущий компонент, но с другим параметром?

Tags: angular2

Допустим, есть маршрут info/id.

В компоненте, который соответствует этому маршруту есть ссылки на другие id.

Как я могу находясь на info/1 нажав на ссылку очутится на info/100500 ?

Пробовал формировать ссылки через `routerLink`, но не работает.

Проводил такие эксперименты:

```
[routerLink]="['page', page.id]"

[routerLink]="['', page.id]"
```

но без результатно.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @overthesanity, а по конкретнее можете указать место, где описано решение проблемы?

Comment: а как вы формилировали routerLink?

Comment: @Komdosh пробовал с пустым первым аргументом и заполненным вторым, пробовал заполнять первый аргумент info/id, но не работало, как я хотел. Относительно текущего положения добавлялись дополнительные уровни.

Comment: покажите кодом, мне не совсем понятно

Comment: @Komdosh , добавил.

Comment: @iluxa1810 решение проблемы описано во всей документации, которую нужно прочитать, это слишком банальный вопрос, поэтому я всегда тыкаю носом в доки, если в документации не описано или зарыто в недрах земли - я даю ответы

Comment: @overthesanity , а могли бы пофармить халявную карму :)

Comment: @iluxa1810 та не, вряд ли вы бы захотели давать ответы в стиле "чтобы использовать `await` в C# метод должен быть помечен ключевым словом `async`" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам необходимо использовать относительный путь текущего расположения, но на один уровень выше `../`

```
[routerLink]="['../', page.id]"
```

**UPD Подписка на изменение параметров**

```
constructor(private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.activatedRouter.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log('This is my page id' + params.id); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Да, маршрут меняется, но страница не рефрешится новыми данными=(

Comment: так а вы подписались на изменение роутинга? в ActivatedRoute

Comment: А какие действия  должен выполнить в подписи?

Comment: очевидно обновление данных

Comment: Т.е если у меня вся инициализация происходит в ngOnInit, то я его должен вызвать в подписке на событие? Я думал, что есть какой-нибудь спец. метод.

Comment: ну подписка и есть спец метод

Comment: А не подскажите, какой? Наткнулся только на это https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2 , но тут говорится про спец. метод для инициализации.

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил, правда не уверен, что у вас называетсся параметр id, можете в консоле вывести params и посмотреть поля